# Calculate average monthly total by groups from data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with a row for each day over a 30 year period with a number of different variable columns. The reason for using data.table is that the .csv file I'm using is huge (approx 1.2 million rows) as there are 30 years worth of data for a number of groups charactertised by a column called 'key'.

An example dataset is shown below:

```
Key   Date          Runoff
A     1980-01-01    2
A     1980-01-02    1
A     1981-01-01    0.1
A     1981-01-02    3
A     1982-01-01    2
A     1982-01-02    5
B     1980-01-01    1.5
B     1980-01-02    0.5
B     1981-01-01    0.3
B     1981-01-02    2
B     1982-01-01    1.5
B     1982-01-02    4
```

The above is a sample of two 'keys', with some data for January over three years to show what I mean. The actual dataset has hundreds of 'keys' and 30 years worth of data for each 'key'.

What I want to do is produce an output that has the total average for each month for each key as is shown below:

```
Key   January  February  March.... etc
A     4.36     ...       ...
B     3.26     ...       ...
```

i.e. the total average for January for Key A = (2 + 1) + (0.1 + 3) + (2 + 5) / 3

When I have done this analysis on one thirty year dataset (i.e. just one key) I have used the following code successfully to achieve this:

```
runoff_tot_average <- rowsum(DF$Runoff, format(DF$Date, '%m')) / 30
```

Where DF is the dataframe for one 30 year dataset.

So could I please have suggestions on how to modify my code above to work with the larger dataset with many 'keys' or offer a completely new solution!

> EDIT

The below code produces the above data example:

```
Key <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
Date <- as.Date(c("1980-01-01", "1980-01-02", "1981-01-01", "1981-01-02", "1982-01-01", "1982-01-02", "1980-01-01", "1980-01-02", "1981-01-01", "1981-01-02", "1982-01-01", "1982-01-02"))
Runoff <- c(2, 1, 0.1, 3, 2, 5, 1.5, 0.5, 0.3, 2, 1.5, 4)
DT <- data.table(Key, Date, Runoff)
```

Comment: Does `runoff_tot_average_A <- rowsum(DF$Runoff[DF$Key=="A"], format(DF$Date, '%m')) / sum(DF$Key=="A")` give what you want ? If no, could you provide a short reproductible example please ?

Comment: Hi Vincent, thanks for offering a solution. I've added a reproducible above for the example dataset. The code you've given would produce an output for each key. What I need is one output with a column for the Key and a column with the total average values for each month.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They only way I could think of doing it was in two steps. Probably not the best way, but here goes

```
DT[, c("YM", "Month") := list(substr(Date, 1, 7), substr(Date, 6, 7))]
DT[, Runoff2 := sum(Runoff), by = c("Key", "YM")]
DT[, mean(Runoff2), by = c("Key", "Month")]

##   Key Month       V1
## 1:   A    01 4.366667
## 2:   B    01 3.266667
```

---

Just to show another (very similar) way:

```
DT[, c("year", "month") := list(year(Date), month(Date))]
DT[, Runoff2 := sum(Runoff), by=list(Key, year, month)]
DT[, mean(Runoff2), by=list(Key, month)]
```

Note that you don't *have* to create new columns, as `by` supports expressions as well. That is, you can directly use them in `by` as follows:

```
DT[, Runoff2 := sum(Runoff), by=list(Key, year = year(Date), month = month(Date))]
```

But since you require to aggregate more than once, it's better (for speed) to store them as additional columns, as @David has shown here.

Comment: Thank you David for initially answering and Arun for the edit. This works well and combining it with the reshape from beginneR's answer I get what I need. I'll mark an answer once I've been able to try the other method as well. J

Comment: I've given this answer the tick as it uses the data.table package that I'm using for most of my analysis.

Answer (score 6):

If you're not looking for complicated functions and just want the mean, then the following should suffice:

```
DT[, sum(Runoff) / length(unique(year(Date))), list(Key, month(Date))]
#   Key month       V1
#1:   A     1 4.366667
#2:   B     1 3.266667
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you said in your question that you would be open to a completely new solution, you could try the following with `dplyr`:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
df$Year.Month <- format(df$Date, '%Y-%m')
df$Month <- format(df$Date, '%m')

require(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Key, Year.Month, Month) %>%
  summarize(Runoff = sum(Runoff)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Key, Month) %>%
  summarize(mean(Runoff))
```

EDIT #1 after comment by @Henrik:
The same can be done by:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Key, Month, Year.Month) %>%
  summarize(Runoff = sum(Runoff)) %>%
  summarize(mean(Runoff))
```

EDIT #2 to round things up:
This is another way of doing it (the second grouping is more explicit this way)
thanks to @Henrik for his comments

```
df %>%
  group_by(Key, Month, Year.Month) %>%
  summarize(Runoff = sum(Runoff)) %>%
  group_by(Key, Month, add = FALSE) %>%    #now grouping by Key and Month, but not Year.Month
  summarize(mean(Runoff))
```

It produces the following result:

```
#Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#Groups: Key
#
#  Key Month mean(Runoff)
#1   A    01     4.366667
#2   B    01     3.266667
```

You can then reshape the output to match your desired output using e.g. `reshape2`. Suppose you stored the output of the above operation in a data.frame `df2`, then you could do:

```
require(reshape2)

df2 <- dcast(df2, Key  ~ Month, sum, value.var = "mean(Runoff)")
```

Comment: +1 For the second you beat me. Nice! cast it with cast(df2, Key~Month)

Comment: @PauloCardoso I saw your (updated) comment just after i edited my question to include the reshape operation

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. The current version of R I'm using cannot support dplyr and I can't download the new version of R until later. I'll let you know how I get on. J

Comment: @beginneR, You may simplify your `dplyr` code slightly. `ungroup() %.% group_by(Key, Month)` may be replaced by `group_by(Key, Month, add = FALSE)`. Or, if you change the order of variables in your first `group_by` to `group_by(Key, Month, Year.Month)`, you don't need the second `group_by` at all. See [**here**](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html): "When you group by multiple variables, each summary peels off one level of the grouping. That makes it easy to progressively roll-up a dataset".

Comment: @Henrik thanks for your comment - that is very nice to know and definitively an improvement. i will update my answer accordingly

Comment: @beginneR, A matter of taste of course, but I tend to prefer the more explicit `group_by(..., add = FALSE)`, instead of the 'automagic' peeling of grouping variables following a `summarise`.

Comment: @Henrik btw `add = FALSE` will be default in dplyr 0.2

Comment: @hadley, Thanks for your info! To me it seems like a more intuitive default.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers. I've given David's answer the tick as it uses the data.table package that I am doing the rest of the analysis in. This solution does work though. If I could give two ticks I would! Thank you.